# Remove categories using Magmi

Tags: category, magmi

Is there a way to quickly remove unwanted categories via Magmi. I know it is possible to delete products en masse using Magmi, is it possible to do this with categories as well using a CSV with a list of categories to be removed?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to your question but it might be a solution to your problem.

run this script:

```
$categoryIds = array(10,11,20); //put all your category ids in an array
foreach ($categoryIds as $id) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
    if ($category->getId()) {
        $category->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, my code : https://justpaste.it/1fybd